# Xbox One not working when Switching Accounts?

Tags: xbox-one

My brother and I want to play each other's games. I've switched his account to my home Xbox and he switched his xbox to my account. I was able to successfully download for example Dark Souls and play but when he logged in to play I got kicked out and was told an error message about logging into the account with the game or buying it.

I read in another forum and the Xbox support website that we could share and play at the same time, for example play online dark souls together. Or is that not a thing anymore? Did I miss a step? Anything else I need to do?

Comment: Are you logging into the same machine? And are you switching accounts or are you logging in at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The kind of sharing you are referring to, requires your brothers HOME Xbox to be the one you are playing from and vice versa.

So if you have 2 Xboxes and 2 accounts:

Your brother's home console needs to be your Xbox, where you then log in with your account to play on.

Your home console needs to be on your brother's Xbox, where he is then logged in with his profile, still able to play your games.

This way is how I have been using it for the past 3 years without any issues.
The important step is to make sure you set each other's Home Console on the other person's Xbox, to ensure he has access to the content, even though he is not logged in.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

My buddy and I 'gameshare' on Xbox.

It's super simple: My Xbox at my house is his 'home console', but I use my account on it. His Xbox at his house is set to *my* 'home console' and he uses his account on it.

My Xbox has access to his games because it's his home console, but I also have access to games purchased with *my account* anywhere I am. He has access to my games because it's my home console, but his account can access any games purchased by his account as well. I buy Monster Hunter - he can play it from his console. He buys DBFz - I can play it from my console. The account that purchased the game can access it from any console, anywhere, anytime - as long as you are the only person signed into that account at the time (obviously).

Both of our account are Xbox Live Gold, and I don't know if that is a requirement - but I'd assume it is if both of your accounts are not Gold. "Play anwhere" might be a feature for online subscriptions.